# как найти среднее арифметическое число чётных элементов массива

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for(let i = 0;i<x.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        console.log(i/3)//не знаю правильно ли???
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема? сложить их и поделить на количество, только четных и все )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var count = 0;
    var summ = 0;
    for(let i = 0;i<x.length; i++){
        if(x[i] % 2 == 0){ //Тут берём число и проверяем чётное ли. i у Вас это ключ
            count += 1; // Если чётное считаем сколько чётных цифр
            summ += x[i]; // Если чётно считаем сумму чётных
        }
    }
    var itog = summ / count; // Выводим среднее - делим сумму на количество.
    
    console.log(itog);
```